# how to parse/extract IP from IPrange/CIDR using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want parse/extract IPs from bulk IPrange or CIDR with list.txt

like iprange:

```
1.0.0.0-1.255.255.255

2.0.0.0-2.255.255.255

3.0.0.0-3.255.255.255
```

or CIDR:

```
1.0.16.0/20

1.0.64.0/18

1.1.64.0/18
```

to IPs

As output.txt :

```
1.10.40.10

10.10.40.10

3.10.40.10
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want the ipaddress package that comes with Python 3.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html

Then you can do for example:

```
import ipaddress
net = ipaddress.ip_network('1.1.64.0/18').hosts()
for ip in net:
   print(ip)
```

It has another method, ipaddress.summarize_address_range, that should covers the other half.